# $location strips slashes from search parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need a url with a query string like this:

```
/api/search/?path=parent/parent/parent/child
```

So I use `$location` like this:

```
$location.search('path', 'parent/parent/parent/child')
```

But it ends up with the delimiters stripped like:

```
/api/search/?path=parentparentparentchild
```

Is there a way to get the unescaped slashes without decoding them? I want to avoid:

```
?path=parent%2Fparent%2Fparent%2Fchild
```

Comment: i mean... `?path=parent/parent/parent/child` would be invalid, would it not? in which case, escaping them would be one of two solutions, the other being not doing it.

Comment: thats probably why they do it then